# Conditional Probability - need help

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I would appreciate if someone can explain the answer to the below question, instead of just saying True or False. Thank you.

**True or False** -

the following scenario depicts an independent relationship between variables (tree growth and air quality):

20% of trees growing in a particular region are not growing to their expected height.

In a particular neighborhood in that region, the Air Quality Index is labeled as “Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups” or worse 30% of the time.

10% of the trees in the region grow in this neighborhood.

If you randomly measured the growth of a tree in that neighborhood, then the probability that that tree is not growing to its expected height is 33.33%.

Comment: You will get better responses on mathSE if you edit your query, re the following article: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933.

Comment: In particular, if you have two events, A and B, how do you determine if these are independent events?  If you are unable to solve the problem, you definitely will want to edit the query to answer this question.